# Libgdx build android project error after update

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 for my libgdx game. I have updated gradle from 2.14.1 to 3.3 and when I try to build android application I get this error (desktop version work correctly)

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/compat/R;
```

I have tried to downgrade gradle version but for Android 2.3.3 I get message that gradle 3.3 is minimum required.

Here is my other settings

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
compileSdkVersion 21

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Please anyone give me solution for phis problem.

EDIT: 
Here is my main build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'Robo Hand'
        gdxVersion = '1.9.7'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        gdxPay = '0.11.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.6.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android:$gdxPay"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-googleplay:${gdxPay}@jar"

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0'


    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-iosrobovm-apple:$gdxPay"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:$gdxPay"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Android build.gradle :

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    compileSdkVersion 21

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }


}

// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
/*
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
*/

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.flexsolutions.diggi.android/AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Upgrade Android studio to 3.0.0

Comment: @Jovan show your `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: name of jars which is inside `libs` folder ?

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan thanks for your response, I removed this line ` compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')` and same error again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finlay I fount what was the problem.It was some duplicate class problem. I put this line of code in android, build.gradle file and my project work again with gradle 3.3

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

I hope this can help others

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade Gradle

Find gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Open root build.gradle file and find artifact in buildscript and change version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Comment/delete google() from repo list inside root build.gradle file

Comment: thanks but as I mention in my question, I'm unable to downgrade gradle version in android studio 2.3.3, I get this error `Error:(49, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1.`